# How do you get all the 4 (or 5) separate weeks in a month from Date() in swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I managed to get data query with "nextDate" property of type Date() in a particular month. In other words all data with dates within that particular month will appear on my tableview when queried. Using the code below and with tweaks I also managed to extract data from the previous and next month.

```
func loadMonthEvents() {
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    var beginningOfMonth: Date?
    var endOfMonth: Date?

    beginningOfMonth = calendar.dateInterval(of: .month, for: date)?.start
        endOfMonth = calendar.dateInterval(of: .month, for: date)?.end

    monthEvents = realm.objects(Events.self).filter("nextDate BETWEEN %@", [beginningOfMonth, endOfMonth]).sorted(byKeyPath: "nextDate", ascending: true)
}
```

Now I want to be able to separate those data according to the week of the month. In my tableView the will be 5 separate headers representing week 1, week 2, week 3, week 4 and week 5(if any). Each separate header will show only event for that week. I tried to apply the weekOfMonth in calendar but it just dont work. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet to find out first and last day of week . You can do this by adding **.weekOfMonth** to the date component . Go through this [official link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/component) and apply accordingly as per your requirement for fetch.
Now i had added two functions / or two button action through which you can get previous week and next week of the month.

```
    var currentDate = Date()
    func weekCalculation()
    {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
//        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        var componentsNow = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .weekOfMonth, .weekday], from: currentDate)
        componentsNow.setValue(1, for: .weekday)
        firstDayOfWeek = calendar.date(from: componentsNow)!
        print(firstDayOfWeek)
        componentsNow.setValue(7, for: .weekday)
        lastDayOfWeek = calendar.date(from: componentsNow)!
        print(lastDayOfWeek)
        let addDaysCount = 0
        var comps = DateComponents()
        comps.setValue(addDaysCount, for: .weekday)
        var comps1 = DateComponents()
        comps1.setValue(-6, for: .day)
        let newDate1 = calendar.date(byAdding: comps1, to: lastDayOfWeek)
        let newDate2 = calendar.date(byAdding: comps, to: lastDayOfWeek)
//        print(newDate1!,newDate2!)
        let firstDay = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate1!)
        let lastDay = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate2!)
//        ShowBanner(title: "", subtitle: firstDay)
        let dF = DateFormatter()
        dF.dateFormat = "d MMMM yyyy"
        let fDayToShow = dF.string(from: newDate1!)
        let lDayToShow = dF.string(from: newDate2!)
        let dateString = String(format: "%@ - %@",fDayToShow,lDayToShow)
        print(firstDay,lastDay)
    }

    @IBAction func nextWeekBtnPressed(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
//        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        let dF = DateFormatter()
        dF.dateFormat = "d MMMM yyyy"
        let addDaysCount = 7
        var comps = DateComponents()
        comps.setValue(addDaysCount, for: .weekday)
        var comps1 = DateComponents()
        comps1.setValue(3, for: .day)
        let newDate1 = calendar.date(byAdding: comps1, to: lastDayOfWeek)
        let newDate2 = calendar.date(byAdding: comps, to: lastDayOfWeek)
        let firstDay = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate1!)
        let lastDay = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate2!)
        let fDayToShow = dF.string(from: newDate1!)
        let lDayToShow = dF.string(from: newDate2!)
        //print(firstDay,lastDay)
        let dateString = String(format: "%@ - %@",fDayToShow,lDayToShow)
        //print(dateString)
        weekCalculation()
    }

    @IBAction func previousWeekBtnPressed(sender: UIButton)
    {
            let calendar = NSCalendar.current
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
//            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
            let addDaysCount = -7
            var comps = DateComponents()
            comps.setValue(addDaysCount, for: .weekday)
        var comps1 = DateComponents()
        comps1.setValue(-10, for: .day)
        let newDate1 = calendar.date(byAdding: comps1, to: lastDayOfWeek)
            let newDate2 = calendar.date(byAdding: comps, to: lastDayOfWeek)
            let firstDay = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate1!)
            let lastDay = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate2!)
            let dF = DateFormatter()
            dF.dateFormat = "d MMMM yyyy"
            let fDayToShow = dF.string(from: newDate1!)
            let lDayToShow = dF.string(from: newDate2!)
            let dateString = String(format: "%@ - %@",fDayToShow,lDayToShow)
        weekCalculation()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Diksha. The code you've provided will define the dates for the current week of the month. What above the other 3 or 4 weeks either before or after the current week in a given month? Sorry I am very very new to all this. Thanks again.

Comment: @halim Welcome . Please check the updated answer where i had used two button action to find out next and previous weeks . Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Diksha. I’ll try the code and get back to you. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the range of weeks from your two dates by doing

```
let w1 = calendar.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: beginningOfMonth!)
print(w1.weekOfYear)

let w2 = calendar.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: endOfMonth!)
print(w2.weekOfYear)
```

And then you could do the same for the date of each event to group the event to a specifik week

Comment: Thank Joakim but I don't understand it. I though we need to define the beginning  and end of each weekOfMonth (4 or 5 of them depending on the month) in order to query the dates using "nextDate BETWEEN %@" as above. Maybe you can ellaborate further as to how to apply your code.

Comment: Joakim, I finally understood how to implement your code i.e. by adding your code to the the one I have and make a little change to the query. But once I ran the code the app crashed and i got this message from the console :Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason: 'NSArray objects must be of type date for BETWEEN operations'.

Comment: I thought you would use `beginningOfMonth` and `endOfMonth` to query Realm and then get week numbers from the result returned by your Realm query. Anyway the error message implies you are using something else than Date in your array, perhaps week numbers? But your database (or Realm) doesn't understand week numbers so you need to handle week numbers in code and get them from the result returned from the query rather than using them in the query.

Comment: I totally misunderstood your suggestion.  What I did was to change the query to make w1 and w2 as the start and end of the week and realm will find dates between w1 and w2. Frankly I don’t even know how to use your code after the realm gives out the result.